# Mapping edges between old and new network dataset using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, esri-geodatabase, network-dataset

For reporting purposes, we are storing the edges of the street in our database after solving the route. Our worry is that, whenever we will receive a new network dataset, the edge Object Id might be changed. As per our past experience, it is a very much likely scenario.

Is there any way to map the edge in the old and new network dataset using ArcGIS Pro?

For example, "88 Avenue" edge object id is 101 in the old network dataset and 201 in the old network dataset. I want to identify that 101 and 201 are the same edge only.

Comment: When you say "ArcGIS" do you mean ArcGIS Pro, ArcMap or another application from the ArcGIS platform?

Comment: I am ok with any ArcGIS application for a possible solution. For now, we are using ArcGIS Pro, ArcMap and ArcCatalog.

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap/ArcCatalog you wish to ask about in this particular question.

Comment: @PolyGeo I would prefer to go with ArcGIS Pro but if we have a solution in ArcMap/ArcCatalog then I am open for it and that's the reason I kept all 3 options. Can you please open this question? I have added a tag for ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: I've focused your question on ArcGIS Pro so that you can tell us more about what you've tried with that and where you are stuck; and so that we can offer suggestions using ArcGIS Pro.  If you wish to also ask about the ArcMap/ArcCatalog architecture, then please do that in a separate question.

Comment: @PolyGeo - thank you for editing it. We did R&D but didn't find any reference link where they have mentioned a way to do a map? Can you please provide some pointers?